# How should I replace this rotten window header?

Tags: bathroom, windows, studs, replacement, demolition

Here I have a corner bathroom. Left wall is exterior. My “header/top plate” is rotten. I am able to put my finger through it.

I have never come across a window header that doubles as a wall top plate, but here we are. I am bracing the rafters and attempting to remove the header. It is double 2x4. Staggered at the left corner obviously.

I would like to downsize the window without dropping it. Would this be a viable option in the future? For now I am just replacing the rotted stuff. New kings, new header etc. Exterior is diagonal 1x8 plank with asbestos and vinyl siding.
Could I replace the header now, without modification in the future? Is there a minimum distance I would have to drop it?
Everything else I have encountered in this house is built very... odd. So why not this? Has anyone seen this in the past?

[image]

Comment: Please _revise_ to clarify. New information doesn't belong down here in comments. Thanks.

Comment: [Edit] your question into the post, don't ask it in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put in a header and change the window later.
I would say that header is two small for the span to start with so installing a narrower window with new cripples will be better from the looks of it.

Make sure to provide enough support, even though the wood is rotten it can be surprising how much support it still provides.

If using wet wood remember it shrinks, this is a place where I want dry wood on a repair so shrinkage won’t be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I actually do agree with Ed here that a header in a weight bearing wall such as this is a good idea....but I do understand your desire to maintain the current window height (you're probably wanting to maintain the aesthetic of the exterior and maintain the same header height as the rest of the windows). Tough call on this one  To repair this properly as Ed said, you should have a double 2x6 header hear with 1/2" flitch plate (flitch plate 1/2" ply or osb to bring the header to 3 1/2" wide to match your wall width. There is only a wrong way to do this and maintain your aesthetic, and that is to fashion a false wall to support your Ellis jacks while you are cutting out and replacing the damaged top plate. For this degree of damage there is most certainly a water intrusion issue at play here...make sure you address whatever failure there is in the water barrier here while you are in this process. Good luck to you

Comment: Please take the [tour]. You'll note that writing up another answer that, effectively, says "I agree with someone else's answer" isn't how we roll here.